# Capybara/RSpec - Checking the content of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'd like to refactor my code, from potentially three lines to just one.

Here's the snippet:

```
    # capture an array of the three stats: impressions/clicks/AVT

    stats = page.all('.sub')

    # check our array.... 

    expect(stats[0]).to have_content("Impressions")
    expect(stats[1]).to have_content("Clicks")
    expect(stats[2]).to have_content("Average")
```

I need a balance of the Capybara `have_content` with the RSpec `contain_exactly`.

Something like:

```
expect(stats).to contain_exactly("Impressions", "Clicks", "Average")
```

Which results in:

```
Failure/Error: expect(stats).to contain_exactly("Impressions", "Clicks", "Average")
   expected collection contained:  ["Average", "Clicks", "Impressions"]
   actual collection contained:    [#<Capybara::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]">, #<Capybara::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]">, #<Capybara::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/abbr/div[1]">]
   the missing elements were:      ["Average", "Clicks", "Impressions"]
   the extra elements were:        [#<Capybara::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]">, #<Capybara::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]">, #<Capybara::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/abbr/div[1]">]
```

How would one refactor this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
# capture an array of the three stats: impressions/clicks/AVT

stats = page.all('.sub').map(&:text)

expect(stats).to contain_exactly("Impressions", "Clicks", "Average")
```

**Update**

Starting with Rspec 3, you could do the following, if you're looking for partial matching:

```
expect(stats).to contain_exactly(
                                 a_string_matching(/Impressions/),
                                 a_string_matching(/Clicks/),
                                 a_string_matching(/Average/)
                                )
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, except now I think I just created more work for myself, since those 3 keywords are part of a larger, dynamic string, and therefore won't pass a in a "contain_exactly" assertion. IE "Overall Impressions 0".